# Is there a way to add all app icons in one go (one time) instead of adding all of them individually one by one?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

There are 17 different sizes app icons which I've to add manually one by one in Xcode. Is there any way I can just copy and paste all icons somewhere inside project and have Xcode accept them?

Possible?

Comment: I use a third party app that both (a) takes a single image and creates all the icons and (b) loads them into a folder I drag into my project. Considering it's an app (with in-app purchases for other functionality) I'm guessing the answer is no.

Comment: You can create a template xasset foler and copy and paste it in the folder structure of the project. You can use this website https://makeappicon.com/ to create all the icons and copy them to the correct project folder. Any other method currently doesn't exist to my knowing (3+ years iOS dev).

Comment: Sorry guys may be I wasn't so clear. I'm not asking how to generate app icons of different sizes. I'm asking how do I import all these 17 icons (already generated) into project without dragging and dropping them one by one (17 times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are apps which generates app icons for all device and create .appiconset file which you can directly drag and drop in .xcassets folder in Xcode

Comment: I believe the OP asks for how to do it without a third party app. (We probably use the same app, and remember, asking for such things is out of scope for this site.)

Comment: out of curiosity, what app do you use?

Comment: I use Icon Set Creator 

[Here is the link ] (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icon-set-creator/id939343785?mt=12)

Comment: Tx that's what I was looking for ;) All I needed was to drag this appiconset (folder) into assets and it did the job.

Comment: I tried to drag the appiconset folder into assets and Xcode its treating it like an image asset rather than icon asset.  Has anyone tried this in Xcode 9? thx :)

Comment: Sad that this 3rd party app does not create a set from a folder of already generated icons :'(